# Extract a word from string using regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have c# code in which I run a perl file using commandline and capture that output in a c# string. I want to extract a certain word from this string using regex. I tried several methods to capture that specific word but it didnt work.

For example: the below text was captured in a string in c#

> CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
>   
> UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
>   
> Initializing.
>   
> jsdns jsdnjs wuee uwoqw duwhduwd 9-8 is = COM10
>   
> uuwe sodks asjnjx

In the above code I want to extract COM10. Similarly this value can also change to COM12 or COM8 or COM15. I will always have COM in the text but the succeeding number can change.

Can someone let me know how to go about with regex. I used RegexOptions.Multiline but am not sure how to go about it. Also if an explanation is included it would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following regex.

```
Match m = Regex.Match(input, @"\b(?i:com\d+)");
if (m.Success)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value); //=> "COM10"
```

**Explanation**:

```
\b       # the boundary between a word character (\w) and not a word character
(?i:     # group, but do not capture (case-insensitive)
  com    #   'com'
  \d+    #   digits (0-9) (1 or more times)
)        # end of grouping
```

[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/G1K7Ux)

Answer (score 1):

```
string thestring = @"CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory. 
UNC paths are not supported. Defaulting to Windows directory. 
Initializing. 
jsdns jsdnjs wuee uwoqw duwhduwd 9-8 is = COM10 
uuwe sodks asjnjx";

string matchedString = Regex.Match(thestring,@"COM[\d]+").Value;
```

The Regex that is matched against the string (`COM[\d]+`) means:

match an instance of COM followed by at least one instance (`+`) of a digit (`\d`)

This is assuming there is only one instance of COM(NUMBER) in your string.

You can also put a space to make sure that only space COM is matched by the Regex, like so:

```
string matchedString = Regex.Match(thestring,@"\sCOM[\d]+").Value;
```

Comment: use `\b` before `COM` to match only `COM` instead of `XCOM`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex like this:

```
\b(COM\d+)\b
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/gJ3bF7/1)**

[image]